# Filtering Sigma.Js graph from external events

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I have an instance of Sigma.Js 1.0.0 rendering a graph in my Canvas element. (The code is below, but you can simply scroll to [Step 2 of Tutorial on the main sigmajs.org page](http://www.sigmajs.org).

As you can see from that code, when the node is clicked, clickNode event occurs, which then applies filtering to the graph, showing only the clicked node and its neighborhood and dimming the others. That's quite clear.

However, how would I make exactly the same thing happen from the outside? Suppose I have the graph rendered already and I have a Tag Cloud next to it. And I want that when I click on a #hashtag, only that node is shown in the graph and the rest are dimmed. How would I do that?

Thanks!

```
<div id="sigma-container"></div>
<script src="path/to/sigma.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/sigma.parsers.min.gexf.js"></script>
<script>
  // Add a method to the graph model that returns an
  // object with every neighbors of a node inside:
  sigma.classes.graph.addMethod('neighbors', function(nodeId) {
    var k,
        neighbors = {},
        index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

    for (k in index)
      neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

    return neighbors;
  });

  sigma.parsers.gexf(
    'path/to/les-miserables.gexf',
    {
      container: 'sigma-container'
    },
    function(s) {
      // We first need to save the original colors of our
      // nodes and edges, like this:
      s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
        n.originalColor = n.color;
      });
      s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
        e.originalColor = e.color;
      });

      // When a node is clicked, we check for each node
      // if it is a neighbor of the clicked one. If not,
      // we set its color as grey, and else, it takes its
      // original color.
      // We do the same for the edges, and we only keep
      // edges that have both extremities colored.
      s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
        var nodeId = e.data.node.id,
            toKeep = s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
        toKeep[nodeId] = e.data.node;

        s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
          if (toKeep[n.id])
            n.color = n.originalColor;
          else
            n.color = '#eee';
        });

        s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
          if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target])
            e.color = e.originalColor;
          else
            e.color = '#eee';
        });

        // Since the data has been modified, we need to
        // call the refresh method to make the colors
        // update effective.
        s.refresh();
      });

      // When the stage is clicked, we just color each
      // node and edge with its original color.
      s.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
        s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
          n.color = n.originalColor;
        });

        s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
          e.color = e.originalColor;
        });

        // Same as in the previous event:
        s.refresh();
      });
    }
  );
</script>
<!-- [...] -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this goes some way to answering your question.

You have a tagcloud full of words, and when a word is clicked, you want to trigger the neighbors method on your sigma instance, for which you need the node id.
Simply put, you need the function which is called when the #hashtag is clicked, to be in the same scope as the sigma instantiation.

```
s= new sigma({
    settings: {...}
})
//more code instantiating methods etc
//let's assume your tags are in elements with class='tagword' and have the hashtag stored in a 'name' attribute
$('.tagword').on('click', function(){
    var name = this.attr('name');
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n){
        if (n.label == name){
            //use the node to trigger an event in sigma
            //i.e. s.graph.neighbors(n.id);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: I think it should be: if (n.label == name){